# GWT: What classes get downloaded when you run GWT.runAsync?

Tags: java, gwt

I've seen `GWT.runAsync(...)` called from inside a module's `onModuleLoad()` method, as well as in other methods, so it seems like it is "legal" to pull down a fragment from anywhere inside a GWT app.

But this got me thinking: if you can fire off the downloading of a codesplitted fragment from anywhere inside your app, then what are the Java classes (which at runtime have already been compiled into JavaScript) that actually get pulled down when you run this method? Obviously this is configurable, but I can't find any code examples that show how to configure what gets pulled back from the server-side. Even in the [official doc on Codesplitting](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting) there are only client-side examples of how to *call* `GWT.runAsync`, but not how to wire it up to a server-side fragment.

In the [JavaDocs](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/core/client/GWT.html#runAsync%28com.google.gwt.core.client.RunAsyncCallback%29) this method is overloaded and has two variants:

- `runAsync(java.lang.Class<?> name, RunAsyncCallback callback)`; and
- `runAsync(RunAsyncCallback callback)`

I'm *guessing* that the former allows you to specify the specific class you want to pull back from the server? If that's the case, is there any configuration you have to do (configuring a classpath, searchpath, etc.) so that the class can be found on the server at runtime, and pulled back?

Most importantly, how does the latter overload work?! If you're not specifying the class to pull back, how does GWT know what to pull back?

**Example**

Say my app has the following `Something` class in it, which then gets (somehow) placed inside one of a particular module's fragments, and then compiled into JavaScript. Furthermore, let's say that I configure things correctly so that the fragment that `Something` lives inside of is deferred and doesn't download with the modules initial fragment (thus it is not "living" inside the client browser yet).

```
public class Something {
    // ... Whatever
}
```

Now the user clicks a button widget, and I want the fragment containing `Something` to download so we can create a `Something` instance and do something with it. **How do I use `GWT.runAsync` to specify the fragment containing `Something`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Thomas posted above, the GWT compiler figures out which fragments it needs automatically. It does so by analyzing your code and tracing all possible execution paths to see which code can be reached from where. For example, let's say you have classes A (the main entry point class), B, C, D, E, F, and G and you have the following **direct** calls (i.e. not using GWT.runAsync):

- A calls B
- B calls C
- D calls E
- F calls E

Then the compiler will (likely) split your code into the following blocks:

- A, B, C (which gets loaded immediately as A is needed immediately
- D (which gets loaded when GWT.runAsync is called on D)
- E (which gets loaded when GWT.runAsync is called on D, E or F)
- F (which gets loaded when GWT.runAsync is called on F)
- G (which gets loaded when GWT.runAsync is called on G)

There have been recent changes (in GWT 2.5) in the way that the splitting is done exactly to optimize the download size of shared segments (E in the above example).

So, while there is no setting per se that allows you to configure the exact content of the split points, you can "choose" them by how you structure your code. It would likely be way too hard for you anyway to keep track of all dependencies manually to make sure all needed code is available.

If you are interested in seeing how the compiler packaged your code and why, you can turn on [compile reports](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompileReport). Here, GWT will not only show you the size and contents of each package, but also the execution path (the A calls B, B calls C from above) that caused each content to be included in the segment. It's really quite an amazing tool.

So, in summary: Play around with your code a little to make sure you understand how and why the compiler makes its packaging decisions, but beyond that, just sit back and let the GWT compiler do its awesome magic! :)

UPDATE:

Re: your added example: The beauty is, the GWT compiler knows which segment to load, so you don't need to tell it anything. All this happens behind the scenes and you don't need to worry about making it happen (but understanding what is happening can be quite useful).

Comment: PS: I organize my projects into subfolders (one for each "application section"), where I have one "main" class for each section, which is called with runAsync. I make sure that I never call into one of these sections except through this main class via runAsync. Then, the folder structure of my project roughly mirrors the code sections that the compiler will likely create. Works beautifully. And the compile reports help me find "bugs" where I do call into a section without using runAsync by accident.

Comment: Thank you for such a helpful answer (+1)! If you don't mind I have a few followups for you. (1) Are you saying that fragmentation happens automatically (with zero-config for the developer), and that the only way to influence fragmentation is to structure you code correctly (by "structure" I mean the way classes call other classes)? (2) If that's the case, then I see a huge problem with this setup: if I don't know how GWT automatically fragmented my code, then how do I know (on the client-side, via `GWT.runAsync`) *when* to pull down more code?...

Comment: ...Using your example above (classes `A` through `G`), if the compiler split `D` into its own block, and I had no control over this, then how do I know to call `GWT.runAsync` to pull down `D` when I need it?!?

Comment: @BanthaFodder: To your questions: 1) Yes, it's zero-config exactly as you described. 2) That's the beauty of it! The GWT compiler knows how it split things up and how it named the segments, so it will replace the GWT.runAsync call with the needed code to automatically load the required segment without you having to tell it which one it is.

Comment: @BanthaFodder: If you don't ALWAYS use GWT.runAsync when you call D, the compiler will not split it up into a separate segment, so the answer to your second comment is: you need to ALWAYS use GWT.runAsync to access any method on D. You wrap up the actual function call you would like to do on D into the callback that you pass into the runAsync call.

Comment: I'm starting to understand...please read my comment underneath user905374's answer - although your answer brought me 95% of the way there, I believe his/her answer is the last piece of the puzzle that I'm missing. Can you confirm whether my summary of his/her answer is correct? If so, I think I finally "get" it. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again Markus - I want to love GWT, I really do, and am beginning to love it, but have just not been able to make sense of their docs at all. Even the sample apps that come with GWT SDK are lousy and don't even make use of the Acticities/Places framework. Thanks for helping me connect the dots.

Comment: Once you manage to wrap your head around it, I'm sure you will love it and just smile at the poor folks still dealing with browser incompatibility and non-existent type-safety in javascript... ;) I really don't understand why this hasn't taken off more quickly. For me, it's the most amazing coding tool since Eclipse! It's unbelievable the things you can make work (bug free, if there is such a thing) with it in a fairly short amount of time. So, hang in there! The fruits of your labor shall be plenty! ;)

Comment: I can't speak for anybody else, but I've been a Spring developer for 5 years and a Java generalist for almost twice that. I don't think GWT is really all that complicated, but the documentation for it is just plain bad. Not un-thorough, but bad. The GWT docs and SDK samples are voluminous and very well put together, but they aren't written from a newcomer's perspective. IMHO they really need to be re-written to ease newbies into it gently. Look at how simple the concept of codesplitting is, and how difficult it was for me to understand it until you were able to put it into simple terms!

Comment: For the most parts of the docs you are absolutely correct. I was lucky enough to be there in the very early days (I actually attended the first Google I/O conference in 2008), when things were still a little simpler. Speaking of which, all the talks from Google I/O 2008-1012 where they introduce GWT (among other tools) are available as videos online. There are some real gems in there that cover many of the interesting details of GWT, like code splitting. I've always found those very helpful. Good way, also, to pass an hour here or there and to get to know some of the guys behind the tool.

Answer (score 1):

It's not configurable, it's determined by the GWT compiler. There's nothing special to do at runtime, the compiler simply splits the generated JavaScript in several `.cache.` files instead of generating a single one, and replaces the `GWT.runAsync` with code to load the appropriate `.cache.` file.

Comment: Thanks (+1), but what am I missing here? I think you're not understanding my question. What I am asking is this: how do I control on the client-side (via `GWT.runAsync`) what gets pulled down on the server-side? If this isn't configurable like you say, then how do I have any confidence that when I run `GWT.runAsync`, I'll be getting the code that I actually need? That's where my confusion is coming from. Thanks again

Comment: I have updated my question with an example at the bottom to help make my question more clear.

Comment: You do not _put something in a fragment_, fragments are inferred from `GWT.runAsync` calls. So, you don't _specify which fragment to load_ using `GWT.runAsync`, you actually _define_ a fragment (actually, a _possible_ fragment, the compiler will figure out whether it deserves to be split)

Comment: OK, this is beginning to make more sense...then I think at the root of my confusion is this: how do you define a (possible) fragment. If I can see code for fragment definition, it might help me connect all the dots. Thanks again.

Comment: This is _inferred_ from the `GWT.runAsync` calls!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that inside runAsync you create an instance of the class MyUIScreen. If that class is not referenced anywhere else in your code, and the only place is in runAsync, then the compiler will figure this out and will break your code into MyUIScreen and everything else.
That's roughly what's going to happen. So the code fragment will be downloaded the moment you access it from runAsync

Comment: Ahhhhh....(light bulb beginning to turn on), +1! So the key to codesplitting is to try and organize your code so that classes instantiated inside a single, particular `GWT.runAsync` call *only* get used inside that call, and nowhere else. That way, the GWT compiler is likely to say "OK, this block of code has no dependencies, so it is safe to place inside its own fragment." Is this a correct summary of how it works? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes that's how it works. Must not have references elsewhere. Compiler decides how tos plit.